# New Lines to HTML Line Breaks Using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, line-breaks

I have the following XML:

```
<RichText>
    Text
    Text
    Text
</RichText>
```

I would like to output the following HTML using XSLT 1.0 (2.0 if I really really have to):

```
<p>
    Text<br/>
    Text<br/>
    Text
</p>
```

I've tried using the following XSL which gets close:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>

  <!-- Because we would rely on $text containing a line break when using 
      substring-before($text,'&#10;') and the last line might not have a
      trailing line break, we append one before doing substring-before().  -->
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text,'&#10;'),'&#10;')"/>
  <br/>

  <xsl:if test="contains($text,'&#10;')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
<xsl:template>
```

This outputs:

```
<p><br>                  
    Text<br>                  
    Text<br>                  
    Text<br>
<br></p>
```

Comment: Can you explain the criteria when to transform a line break character to a `br` element and when not? You have given one example but perhaps formulating the criteria in plain text helps you writing the XSLT checks or allows us helping you write them.

Comment: What kind of output do you want if there were empty lines between those `Text` lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your XSLT 1.0 solution, I think all you need is some `xsl:if` tests to test if there is non-white space text before and after the current line you are handling.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="RichText">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>

   <xsl:variable name="startText" select="substring-before(concat($text,'&#10;'),'&#10;')" />
   <xsl:variable name="nextText" select="substring-after($text,'&#10;')"/>
   <xsl:if test="normalize-space($startText)">
       <xsl:value-of select="$startText"/>
      <xsl:if test="normalize-space($nextText)">
         <br />
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:if>

   <xsl:if test="contains($text,'&#10;')">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$nextText"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="RichText">
    <p>
      <xsl:variable name="txt" select="tokenize(., '&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="len" select="count($txt)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="subsequence($txt, 2, $len - 2)">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;br/&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I used XSLT 2.0, as a version MUCH simpler to write.

It is possible to rewrite it using XSLT 1.0, but you must use equivalent
*1.0* solutions for:

- tokenization,
- subsequence,
- and trimming.